# How do we justify that $|A+h\setminus A|\to 0$ as $|h|\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset \Bbb R^d$ be a measurable set and note its translation $A+h= \{a+h: a\in A\}$ for $h\in \Bbb R^d$.

Let $|A|= \lambda(A)$ be the Lebesgue measure of $A$.
It is well known that $|A+h|= |A|$.

Assume $|A|<\infty$. How we show that $|A+h\setminus A|\to 0$ as $|h|\to 0$ and $|A\setminus A+h|\to 0$ as $|h|\to 0$?

How to apply the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\bigcup_n (A_n+h)=(\bigcup_n A_n)+h$

You must prove that $|A \cap A+h| \to |A|$ as $h \to 0$

Since $A$ has finite measure then $|A|+|A+h|-|A \cap A+h|=|A \cup (A+h)|$

So if we prove that $|A \cup (A+h)| \to |A|$ ,we are done.

Assume firstly that $A= Q$ a cube in $\Bbb{R}^d$.This is easy to prove.

If $A$ is open then $A=\bigcup_n I_n$,a disjoint union of dyadic cubes $I_n$

Now if $\epsilon>0$ then exists $N \geq 1$ such that $\sum_{n>N}^{\infty}|I_n \cup I_n+h|<\epsilon$ because $\sum_n|I_n \cup (I_n+h)| \leq 2|A|<+\infty$

Also $A \cup A+h \subseteq \bigcup_n(I_n \cup I_n+h)$

So $|A \cup A+h| \leq \sum_{n=1}^N |(I_n+h) \cup I_n| +\epsilon$

Thus $$\limsup_{h \to 0}|A \cup A+h| \leq \sum_{n=1}^N|I_n| +\epsilon \leq |A|+\epsilon$$

From this you can derive the conclusion since $|A \cup A+h| \geq |A|,\forall h \in \Bbb{R}^d$

Comment: We are in Euclidean space.. not in one dimension

Comment: Thanks, for this nice answer. But I can't still figure out why this obvious for cubes

Comment: @GuyFsone try it on squares in two dimensions..